Add border to BottomAppBar with CircularNotchedRectangle
I currently have this tabbar:

However, as you can see, my background will be fully white, and so will the tabbar be. So it's hard to distinguish. I am looking for a way to add a border, following the notched outline. But I can't seem to figure it out.
This is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'progress.dart';
import 'profile.dart';
import 'search.dart';

class FabTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  FabTabs({super.key, required this.selectedIndex});

  @override
  State<FabTabs> createState() => _FabTabsState();
}

class _FabTabsState extends State<FabTabs> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  void onItemTapped(int index){
    setState(() {
      widget.selectedIndex = index;
      currentIndex = widget.selectedIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    onItemTapped(widget.selectedIndex);
    super.initState();
  }

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    const Home(),
    const Progress(),
    const Search(),
    const Profile()
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget currentScreen = currentIndex == 0 ? const Home() : currentIndex == 1 ? const Progress() : currentIndex == 2 ? const Search() : const Profile();

    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: PageStorage(
        bucket: bucket,
        child: currentScreen,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          print("add fab button");
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 10,
        color: Colors.white,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 10,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 50,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = const Home();
                        currentIndex = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.home_filled,
                          color: currentIndex == 0 ? const Color(0xFF503e75) : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "",
                          style: TextStyle(color: currentIndex == 0 ? const Color(0xFF503e75) : Colors.grey),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 50,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = const Progress();
                        currentIndex = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                          color: currentIndex == 1 ? const Color(0xFF503e75) : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "",
                          style: TextStyle(color: currentIndex == 1 ? const Color(0xFF503e75) : Colors.grey),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 50,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = const Search();
                        currentIndex = 2;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.person_pin_outlined,
                          color: currentIndex == 2 ? const Color(0xFF503e75) : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "",
                          style: TextStyle(color: currentIndex == 2 ? const Color(0xFF503e75) : Colors.grey),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 50,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = const Profile();
                        currentIndex = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.more_horiz_outlined,
                          color: currentIndex == 3 ? const Color(0xFF503e75) : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "",
                          style: TextStyle(color: currentIndex == 3 ? const Color(0xFF503e75) : Colors.grey),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I found this identical question, where they suggest using ClipPath, but I don't know how to implement it: Add border to notched bottom nav bar Flutter?
